# Setting a Value of a Textbox in Javascript in the URL bar of Chrome just writes the value to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to set the value of a textbox in a webpage to a certain value by entering this into the url bar:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("textboxID").value = "Value";
```

However whenever I do it just returns a blank screen with whatever value I was trying to set written in the corner.

I am using Google Chrome and I know that this problem does not occur on just one website as I have tried it on many, which leads me to believe that the problem is with the browser, not the site.

Does anyone know why this is happening or a way I can set the value of a textbox on a page using javascript in the URL bar?

Thanks,
  -p0iz0n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting void 0 at the end doesn't clear the content of the webpage.

```
javascript:document.getElementById("textboxID").value = "Value";void 0
```

undefined works, but void 0 is more popular

Answer (score 3):

Enter it into the console:

- right click on the page
- select 'inspect element*
- in the new panel, select 'console'
- enter your command and hit return