# Use URLbar to change textbox value? (JavaScript maybe?)

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can use the URLbar to change the value (the text) of a textbox?

I can type "javascript:alert(document.lastModified)" into the URLbar, and it runs just fine--how can I run some javascript that says "Change X textbox's value to = Y"?

Comment: Using the same DOM APIs that you use elsewhere in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to run it the same way:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('IDOFTEXTBOX').value='something';
```

Comment: Thank you! Just realized that void makes all the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729343/setting-a-value-of-a-textbox-in-javascript-in-the-url-bar-of-chrome-just-writes